# Sympy and units for electric systems

Tags: python, sympy, units-of-measurement

Is there a way to force Sympy to print Volts as volts instead of returning it as a composition of SI units?

MWE:

```
>>> import sympy.physics.units as u
>>> V = 5 * u.V
>>> print(V)
5*kg*m**2/(A*s**3)
```

### Edit

As pointed by @rfkortekaas, I can define new units using

```
V = u.Unit('V','V')
```

And his suggestion really solves the problem in one side. However if i use

```
>>> I = 0.5 * u.A
>>> R = 100 * u.ohm
>>> V_R = I * R
>>> V_R
50.0*kg*m**2/(A*s**3)
```

I still need to `V_R` to be recognized as "`V`" (voltage)

### Edit 2

Thanks to @rfkortekaas that is still helping me with the issue, now I have:

```
>>> V = u.Unit('V', 'V')
>>> ohm = u.Unit('ohm = V/u.A', '\Omega')
>>> R = (10 * V) / (0.5 * u.A)
>>> R
20.0*V/A
>>> V_R = (0.5 * u.A) * (10 * ohm)
>>> V_R
5.0*A*\Omega
```

i.e. `V/A` nor `A*\Omega` are been recognized as `ohm` and 'V' respectively.

Comment: See my change in the answer. Unfortunately you cannot achieve your latest edit together with the others. This is due to the composition of the equation as Base units. So ohm needs to be a Base unit in order to achieve this, but then either volt or ampere cannot be a Base unit and will then be composed as the other Base units.

Comment: Thanks @rfkortekaas. Do you mind in including your latest comment in the answer?

Comment: I've added it to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All sympy units will be formed as the S.I. base units. So all derived units will be expressed as a compaction of the Base units according to S.I.

Base units are formed by the unit class: sympy.physics.units.Unit('ampere', 'A').

All derived units will be formed by an mathematic operation on the Base (or derived) units.

To define this in your way you can do this as follows:
Ampère is already a base unitso can be used.
Define volt as Unit('volt','V'). And define ohm as a devision of volt by ampere.

Unfortunately it cannot be achieved to have volt, ampere and ohm all as Base units together and get the correct units for each. This is due to the composition of the derived as Base units.

Comment: I checked it and see that you can subclass the Unit class with your own definition: volt=Unit('volt','V'). That way you can print it with a non SI unit.

Comment: @rfkortekass thanks, really useful. It solves the problem from one side. However I need also that `ohm * ampere` to be recognized as voltage. I will update the question.

Comment: Ampère is a base unit and can be used. You also need to redefine ohm so it's formed as 'ohm = V/u.A' where V us your definition of volt and u.A is the Ampère Base unit.

Comment: Thank you again, @rfkortekaas. We are getting closer! I made you last suggestion and it works for one case but not for the other. I will edit the question again as it is hard to write it here.

Comment: Sorry for the delay @rfkortekass, please take a look on the edited question when you have time.

Answer (score 0):

Just here to share how I solved my own problem. The class below holds a list of interesting units and then it is possible to parse the units from Sympy using that list.

```
from sympy.physics import units as u

class Electric:
    units = {}
    units[u.V] = 'V'
    units[u.W] = 'W'
    units[u.A] = 'A' 
    units[u.Hz] = 'Hz'
    units[u.percent] = '\%'
    units[u.F] = 'F'
    units[u.s] = 's'
    units[u.ohm] = '\Omega'

    @classmethod
    def identify_unit(cls, value):
        for unit in cls.units.keys():
            aux = value.as_coefficient(unit)
            if aux:
                if aux.is_number:
                    return aux, cls.units[unit]
        return value

    @classmethod
    def change_factor(cls, value):
        aux = abs(value[0])
        if aux >= u.mega:
            return value[0] / (10 ** 6), "M" + value[1]
        elif aux >= u.kilo:
            return value[0] / (10 ** 3), "k" + value[1]
        elif aux >= 1:
            return value[0], value[1]
        elif aux >= u.milli:
            return value[0] * (10 ** 3), "m" + value[1]
        elif aux >= u.micro:
            return value[0] * (10 ** 6), "\mu{}" + value[1]
        else:
            return value
```

Example of use:

```
>>> V_R = 2 * u.V
>>> print(V_R)
2*kg*m**2/(A*s**3)
>>> print(Electric.identify_unit(V_R))
(2, 'V')
>>> I_R = 1 * u.milli * u.A
>>> print(I_R)
A/1000
>>> print(Electric.identify_unit(I_R))
(1/1000, 'A')
>>> R = V_R / I_R
>>> print(R)
2000*kg*m**2/(A**2*s**3)
>>> a = Electric.identify_unit(R)
>>> print(a)
(2000, '\\Omega')
>>> b = Electric.change_factor(a)
>>> print(b)
(2.00000, 'k\\Omega')
```